# cannot install mssql on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, curl, mssql

```
telecast@telecast-PowerEdge-R210-II:~$ sudo curl -o /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

Anyone know why curl is failing with the `Error in the pull function` message?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: you tagged your post 14.04 but the link you give refers to ubuntu 16.04.

If you want to install SQL server on your ubuntu you will have a to add the Microsoft corresponding repository and use apt-get.

Here is the MS tutorial describing accurately each step to take :

[MS tutorial to install SQL server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017)